# Count words in in hashmap

Tags: java

Not sure if I should be posting this here, but I am not sure if my update can be seen on my last post. I have a program that I need to print out the words that the user enters in as long as they are included in the example.text file (legalEnglishWords) and count them. Right now I am printing everything in the example.text, instead of just the ones entered by the user.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Affine_English2

{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        Map<String, Integer> legalEnglishWords = new HashMap<>();

         Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("example.txt"));

          while (file.hasNextLine())
          {
              String line = file.nextLine();

            for (String word : line.split(" "))
            {
                {
                    legalEnglishWords.put(word, 0);
                }
            }
          } 

            file.close();

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter in a message: ");
            String message = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            scan.close();

            for (String userInput : message.split(" ")) 
            {
                if (legalEnglishWords.containsKey(userInput)) 
                {
                   System.out.println("\"" +userInput + "\" is an English word ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println("");

            for( String word : message.split(" "))
            {
                if (!legalEnglishWords.containsKey(word))
                {
                    legalEnglishWords.put(word, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    legalEnglishWords.put(word, legalEnglishWords.get(word) + 1);
                }   
            }  

            for (String word: legalEnglishWords.keySet()) 
               {
                    System.out.println("the word \"" + word + "\" occurred " + legalEnglishWords.get(word) + " times");
               }
    }
}
```

This is the output

```
Please enter in a message: 
aaat is is this are that

"is" is an English word 
"is" is an English word 
"this" is an English word 
"are" is an English word 
"that" is an English word 

the word "but" occurred 0 times
the word "" occurred 0 times
the word "use" occurred 0 times
the word "had" occurred 0 times
the word "do" occurred 0 times
the word "your" occurred 0 times
the word "when" occurred 0 times
the word "that" occurred 1 times
the word "his" occurred 0 times
the word "from" occurred 0 times
the word "if" occurred 0 times
the word "you" occurred 0 times
the word "they" occurred 0 times
the word "all" occurred 0 times
the word "which" occurred 0 times
the word "in" occurred 0 times
the word "this" occurred 1 times
the word "is" occurred 2 times
the word "it" occurred 0 times
the word "an" occurred 0 times
the word "each" occurred 0 times
the word "she" occurred 0 times
the word "as" occurred 0 times
the word "at" occurred 0 times
the word "word" occurred 0 times
the word "be" occurred 0 times
the word "line" occurred 0 times
the word "for" occurred 0 times
the word "their" occurred 0 times
the word "we" occurred 0 times
the word "can" occurred 0 times
the word "how" occurred 0 times
the word "not" occurred 0 times
the word "are" occurred 1 times
the word "and" occurred 0 times
the word "of" occurred 0 times
the word "by" occurred 0 times
the word "have" occurred 0 times
the word "where" occurred 0 times
the word "said" occurred 0 times
the word "on" occurred 0 times
the word "a" occurred 0 times
the word "or" occurred 0 times
the word "was" occurred 0 times
the word "i" occurred 0 times
the word "the" occurred 0 times
the word "with" occurred 0 times
the word "what" occurred 0 times
the word "there" occurred 0 times
the word "to" occurred 0 times
the word "he" occurred 0 times
the word "aaat" occurred 1 times
```

It does what is intended, counting the number of times the word was used, but it prints every word in the file. It also adds words from the user not included in the file and counts them as well( last line above). This is not what I want. Any help would be great.

Comment: Please paste you input , desire output and the output you are getting now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You should edit your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43509070/4391450) instead of answering it with a question and posting a new one.

Comment: Will do in the future, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had to remove single line:

```
if (!legalEnglishWords.containsKey(word)){
 legalEnglishWords.put(word, 1);// this adds unknown words to your dictionary
}
```

It should then look like this (short version):

```
       for (String userInput : message.split(" ")) {
            if (legalEnglishWords.containsKey(userInput)) {
                System.out.println("\"" + userInput + "\" is an English word ");
                legalEnglishWords.put(userInput, legalEnglishWords.get(userInput) + 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");

        for (String word : legalEnglishWords.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("the word \"" + word + "\" occurred " + legalEnglishWords.get(word) + " times");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not notice the plus one was adding the word to my word set

Answer (score 0):

There are two points:

1. Printing everything: you need to filter the values with an int value `> 0` (Hint: use `entrySet()` to increase performance)

   ```
   for (Entry<String, Integer> word : legalEnglishWords.entrySet())
       if (word.getValue() > 0)
           System.out.println("the word \"" + word.getKey() + "\" occurred " + word.getValue() + " times");
   ```
2. Also printing "new" user input: you put these values into the map via `legalEnglishWords.put(word, 1);`. Now the word is listed in the map and if you wrote the same false word again its count will be increased. If you want to collect false words you may create a new map.